# Are there open questions in Markov chains?

Tags: markov-chains

I would be curious to know if there's still open question about discrete markovian chains

Comment: You might find some of the links at *[What are some open research problems in Stochastic Processes?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321155/what-are-some-open-research-problems-in-stochastic-processes/406022#406022)*.

Answer (score 5):

Chapter 23 of *Markov Chains and Mixing Times* by Levin, Peres, and Wilmer is called "Open Problems". The book is available online [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf).